# Multiple TinyMCE Initialize

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, tinymce, textarea

I try to Initialize multiple TinyMCE text editors on my page and get an error, I get simple text areas. I try to Initialize with class name with HTML tag name and it always doesn't work.

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KijDc.png)

And the first text area (with TinyMCE) is not active, I mean I can't write something in the area.

THE CODE

```
tinymce.init({
            selector: 'textarea',
            plugins: 'link',
            menubar: '',
            toolbar: 'link'
        })
```

Comment: Code ??? Where is your code ?

Comment: Check again, thank you

Comment: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/general-configuration-guide/multiple-editors/

Comment: Can you replicate this behavior with the [TinyMCE fiddle](https://fiddle.tiny.cloud), or anywhere else outside your implementation? Some reproducible examples would be very helpful.